# Printing the whole row of my data from a max value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select the highest value from this data but i also need the month it comes from too, here printing the whole row. Currently i'm using df.max() which just pulls the highest value. Does anyone know how to do this in pandas.

```
#current code
accidents["month"] = accidents.Date.apply(lambda s: int(s.split("/")[1]))
temp = accidents.groupby('month').size().rename('Accidents')

#selecting the highest value from the dataframe
temp.max()

answer given = 10937
answer i need should look like this (month and no of accidents): 11    10937
```

temp dataframe;

```
month
1      9371
2      8838
3      9427
4      8899
5      9758
6      9942
7     10325
8      9534
9     10222
10    10311
11    10937
12     9972
Name: Accidents, dtype: int64
```

would also be good to rename the accidents column to accidents is anyone can help too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is unique (in your case it is) you can simply get a subset of the dataframe.

```
temp[temp.iloc[:,1]==temp.iloc[:,1].max()]
```

So what the code is doing is looking at the integer position (rows then columns) and matching it with your condition, which is the max temp.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work on mine. Seems to return this error code - IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: Then as indicated there are too many indexs in the iloc. In other words, the returned values are in the form of a pandas **series** this means that you simply need to remove :, and it becomes like this temp[temp.iloc[:]==temp.iloc[:].max()]